# svg tspan bounds out of line in IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I have three single-character tspan elements in an svg:text element and in most browsers when I hover the mouse over each one they highlight and all is good. But in IE (checked in both 9 and 10) the bounds for the second tspan start just off center from the first so it is quite easy for a user to think they are clicking on the first tspan while actually clicking on the second.

Here, a picture is worth a thousand words and all that. I've simplified the example for easier debugging. If the cursor ends up on the protruding part of the P, IE thinks the user is clicking on the I.

[image]

The yellow box shows the area that the first ("P") tspan gets focus.
The red box shows the area that the second ("I") tspan gets focus.

```
<text class="titlebar_icon right" ng-attr-x="{{icon_x}}" y="49" x="1200">
    <tspan id="print" class="print" ng-click="onClick('print')">P</tspan>
    <tspan id="help" class="help" ng-click="onClick('help')">I</tspan>
    <tspan id="logo" class="embedded_logo" ng-click="onClick('home')">X</tspan>
</text>
```

The same overlap happens with the third tspan blocking out half the second tspan, it's not in the screenshot because on some pages it has `display:none`.

So, how can I convince IE to put the right bounds around the tspans? Do I have to abandon tspans altogether. The effect I want to achieve is for three single characters to appear in the far right of the menu bar and if any of them are hidden via `display:none`, the others duffle further over to the right. Current done by `text-anchor: end`.

Comment: It's well-known that IE uses a different box model from sane browsers. Have you tried the [old `box-sizing` css property trick](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)?

Comment: Yup, tried that. No dice :-(

Comment: Two solutions: try converting these characters to SVG glyph (or paths) and treat them like any `<image>` or use math to figure out which which letter is closest to `mousedown` event on this `text`